# Trying to load and use a pickled object in an AWS lambda, getting Attribute Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pickle, serverless

I am trying to load a custom object (in a lambda function) which I had pickled earlier. Getting attribute error as

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'my_class' on <module '__main__' from '/var/runtime/bootstrap'>
```

Tried to import the class as suggested by a few posts. (works on local)

```py
from my_class import *
```

but no luck.

I am pickling the object as follows :

the call -

```py
my_class_obj = my_class()
my_class_obj.to_disk(OBJECT_FILE, my_class_obj)
```

The to_disk function is as follows:

```py
def to_disk(self, file_name, data):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data , f)
```

Loading the object in new python file as

```py
new_my_class_obj = from_disk(OBJECT_FILE)
```

The loading method

```py
def from_disk(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

The import * statement resolves the issue on local machine but not in aws lambda. I have included the my_class file in the deployment package of the lambda itself. The object is also packaged with the lambda.

Also using layers for a few dependencies but don't think if that has anything to do with this error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on here. Are you trying to pickle a module? Or `import` everything from a class? You shouldn't be pickling a module, since there isn't any data to save into a `pickle object`. I also don't think you should be trying to import everything from a `class`? I just don't see how that would be relevant/helpful.

Comment: I corrected your title to `AWS Lambda` since a `python lambda` is a [different thing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) entirely.

Comment: That `__main__` thing sounds like when you created the pickle file, the file you were running as a script contained the class of the object you wanted to pickle (or at least the class of some object that would end up pickled as part of pickling the original object). Is that the case? Don't do that; it's one of the cases where Python's awkward `__main__` design breaks things, even if you don't have circular imports.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb thanks for the correction the question.

Comment: @MasonCaiby So I have slots/variables in the object (my_class here) in which I am storing some information and I need this in the new script. (preferably all of them) 
I got around the problem for now by pickling one of the variables (which was a list) directly since I needed it but would like to pickle the whole object. Yes, I agree the import * is not a good idea.

Comment: @MasonCaiby So the thing is pickling the whole object works on the local machine but breaks in aws lambda environment, I am just curious as to is there some way to pickle the object correctly so when I load it again it gets the correct class Attributes. I tried the method where you update ```__module__``` explicitly with the class name but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please point out if any of the above is a bad practice or if there are more technical details that need to be understood to resolve this, either on python side or aws lambda side.

Comment: There are legitimate use cases for Pickle but I would use it only if something like serializing to JSON is not possible. Check ["Don't Picke Your Data (2014)](https://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/). One advantage of a more universal format like JSON is that you are not stuck with Python.

Comment: So if you `initizalize` an instance of a class (`a = MyClass()`) then pickle `a`, it will keep whatever you have done to a when you unpickle it. But it still looks like you are trying to import `from` a class which cannot be done. you import class from modules.

Comment: @MasonCaiby as you can see above I am creating an instance of the class as an object ```my_class_obj``` and pickling that. (Doing this in another script)
I maybe doing the imports wrong as you suggested.

Comment: Without seeing the full error stack, I'm making an educated guess. But it looks like the error is coming from your import statement. That said, I don't know what your directory structure looks like, so you might be import a file called `my_class.py` which exists in you Lambda environment. What attributes do you want that you aren't getting? Are you setting them in the `my_class_obj` instance of your class? It looks like you don't do anything with the class.

Comment: Yes I am updating the attributes in the object before picking it. Didn't include the ```_init__``` function and the updating code in the question. both the script where the obj is loaded from the file and my_class.py reside in the same folder in the lambda. Works on local, fails in Lambda env. I am suspecting this maybe because lambda tries to get everything from /opt/python ?